# (swift) - collectionview doesn't detect cell tab after the first line

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a strange issue on collectionview. I use the function

```
func collectionView(collView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

to detect if a cell of my collectionview is touched, and it works but only for cells in the first row.

Actually, I have 4 items in my collectionview, and on iPhone I display 2 items per row and on iPad, 3 items per row.
So the 4th items is never detected (as always on the 2nd row of my collectionview) but for the 3rd item, the TAP is detected on iPad as it is on the first row, but not detected on iPhone.
That's why I think the issue comes from the number of row.

Is there any particular reason for that ? Or maybe I just make a mistake :)
Thanks !

Comment: Did you implement  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method? try to debug in this method and see if your rows are available.

Comment: thanks for your answer ! I just found the issue. Actually my collectionview is inside a uiview, but the height of the uiview was smaller than the collectionview. So I was able to see the collectionview, the tap was not recognize... To be honest, I don't know why it works like this but now it works :)